# AWS Glue crawler is too slow

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

There is a problem using aws glue.

I am trying to build a data catalog using a crawler, but it takes too long.

Also, it uses too much dynamodb read capacity.

Normally, there wasn't much read capacity, but read capacity increased to 62.

I know that crawler is a function that only generates meta data, but why does it take so long?

After running for about an hour, it took too long to cancel.

Is the crawler reading all data from dynamodb?

my dynamodb

- dynamodb storage size: 66GB
- dynamodb record: 158,296,668
- read/write capacity mode : on-demand

Comment: what is the amount of the data you crawl?

Comment: ```dynamodb record: 158,296,668```
It is a table of dynamodb

Comment: My understanding of a NoSQL databases like DynamoDB, each item could have different attributes besides the Hash Key or your primary key. DynamoDB does not necessarily have the concept of a schema, so to generate metadata, I am assuming it has to scan all the items to understand what sort of metadata should be added to your table. This could be hectic process for a huge table. Maybe, try to create a provisioned table to test how long the crawl takes and benchmark this again your 66GB table.